# How to move from user login to a different ViewController that has SWRevealviewController Menu as its class?

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I know this might be a stupid question, just getting started with swift, my question is how shall i proceed to move the user from Login screen to ViewControllerwith slideoutMenu having SWRevealViewController as Class. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Cin.png)

```
func handleLogin(){
       if let loginVCobj = self.containerCustom.currentViewController 
as? LoginClass
    {
        guard let loginEmail = loginVCobj.LoginName.text else{
            print("No Login Name to submit")
            return
        }
        guard let loginPassword = loginVCobj.LoginPassword.text else {
            print("No Login Password to submit")
            return
        }

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: loginEmail, password: 
loginPassword){ (user, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }
            print("user Logged in")

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let secondViewController =  
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"SWBlankRevealVCStoryBoard") as! SWRevealViewController
            self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, 
completion: nil)
```

Comment: What problem are you facing with your code?

Comment: the app crashes with error : Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x113db7368) to 'SWRevealViewController' (0x11008c238).   All i want to do is to direct the user from the login screen to ViewController that has menu in it. as shown in the image

Comment: Go to your storyboard and select your **SWRevealViewController** and in the class inspector, change the custom class to `SWRevealViewController`

Comment: you mean the identity inspector that has square box on upper left side, yes the custom class name is set as SWRevealViewController

Comment: Yep, sorry that's identity inspector. Btw, make sure you have set the storyboard id correctly in IB and when you are presenting.